# Deleting allocated memory by pointer doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qt4

I'm creating a application in C++ with the QT framework which includes a HTTP POST request.
The value the reply pointer points to doesn't get deleted and causes a memory leak.
I have tried to delete this memory allocation like this:

```
if (reply)
{
    qDebug() << "reply deleted";
    delete reply;
}
reply = m_qnam->post(request, jsonString);
qDebug() << reply;
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(handleNetworkData()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)), this, SLOT(handleSSLErrors()));
```

Whenever I try to do so, the program crashes instantly.
In the header of this class the reply is initiated as a pointer:

```
QNetworkReply * reply;
```

Does anyone know why my program crashes by deleting the memory allocation the pointer points to? What would be a possible solution for my problem?

Comment: Hello Raoul. Just saying that your program crashes is not enough for anyone here to find the error. We could only guess. It would be better to add the output of the crashed program to the question. e.g. is the string "reply delete" in the output? It would also be a good idea to add some more debugging outputs to the code. Just to see where the program crashes. E.g. it could crash because the request  object is deleted with the reply recursively; then the `m_qnam->post(request, jsonString)` would access a deleted object.

Comment: I get the following output, which is not that helpful:
11:39:19: Starting /home/pi/userInterface/build-userInterface-Pi4-Debug/userInterface...
reply deleted 
11:39:20: The program has unexpectedly finished.
11:39:20: The process was ended forcefully.
11:39:20: /home/pi/userInterface/build-userInterface-Pi4-Debug/userInterface crashed.

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that you forgot to give `reply` a valid value.

Comment: If I do not delete the reply, the application doesn't crash. So I think i give reply a valid value.

Comment: Just because `reply` is not null doesn't mean you can delete it. It could be uninitialized, in which case deleting it will likely crash the program.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use reply.deleteLater()

Comment: I have tried that as well. The program doesn't crash anymore, but not all the functionalities of my application (UI) seem to work. Some components are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using raw pointers, you might want to consider switching to Smartpointers (such as `std::unique_ptr`) instead.

Smartpointers make usage of RAII, in which the Instance of the class `std::unique_ptr<T>` holds the pointer and deletes it upon destruction.

To answer your question: it crashes because `reply = m_qnam->post(request, jsonString);` may return a `nullptr` and you (presumably) try to dereference this `nullptr`.